# I'd like to make my discord bot join voice chat every hour

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord.py

i'd like to make join a voice chat every hour and play an mp3 file,with discord.py

```
    @client.command()
    async def join(ctx):
       channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
       voice = await channel.connect()
       source = FFmpegPCMAudio('sound.mp3')
       player = voice.play(source)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What exactly is the problem? Can you explain the problem you have with your code? What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See also [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly modified version of the [documentation's](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) example is:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def cog_unload(self):
        self.joiner.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(hours=1)
    async def joiner(self):
       channel = self.bot.get_channel(<id>)
       voice = await channel.connect()
       source = FFmpegPCMAudio('sound.mp3')
       player = voice.play(source)
```